# Magento2 : Fire body loader with text/x-magento-init

Tags: javascript, magento2.3

i have a custom block on my page, that calls javascript via text/x-magento-init and performs some operations so loader should be displayed untill that script will finish its operations. How can i fire body loader with that block load?

Comment: You can check the below link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243598/how-to-initialize-a-block-loader-on-an-element-which-is-being-loaded-by-knockout?rq=1